# hibernate ejb3+Tomcat+Openejb or Spring+hibernate for an exsiting GWT2 project

Tags: spring, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, gwt2

I used GWT2+DAO pattern for my apps and it's work correctly. Now my BD as grown a lot and i want to manage it more easier.  So I want to use an ORM.What i want to do is to keep my first DAO implementation and use hibernate for my new classes. But I read a lot on internet and I'm very confused about the way to deal with this.

- which solution between hibernate ejb3+Tomcat+Openejb and Spring+hibernate could be better for me?
- also which one could be the fastest?
- Should I change all my dao to use hibernate methods or should I use the both?

NB: I'm just started to read spring doc, but I have already read hibernate doc.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the change you need only affects the back-end, hence has nothing to do with the server or container you are using.

Rather in your DAO, when saving new pojos, use hibernateTemplate instead of what you were using. 
It would be advisable to actually be consistent, if you are going to use hibernate, use hibernate for all your db manipulation.

Optimization is a whole chapter on itself, I think you should focus on getting your db changes for now, then worry about the speed when everything works.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But when I talk about "the fastest" I mean in the implementation. ie. I don't know if using spring would lead me to rebullt my  project structure and then adding too much time in my development process. So I want to know which solution won't change my project structure too much.